# Create custom validation with three different error messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, email, email-validation

I need to create a validation on an email field, i am using MVC 4.

I would use a simple regular expression, however as you see below i need to show three different error messages depending of the input on email field.

Validation Rules:

1)If the @ sign is not present in the email address, display the message:  @ sign is required.

2) If no period (.) is entered, display the message:  Period (.) after the @ sign is required.

3) If 2 characters are not present after the period,  display the message:  Must contain at least 2 characters after the period.

Comment: add what you tried so far

Comment: Whats wrong with just using the `[EmailAddress]` attribute?